# How to extract the information from one resume using lucene

Tags: lucene

everyone!

I am a fresh man to Lucene.

And I am working on a resume filter project using lucene . Firstly I want to extract some basic informations such as bithday etc from the resumes .

Suppose there is always one line says that birthday: 1989/10/19 or something like this . How could I extract this kind of info with Lucene instead of directly using regular expression.

currently I find maybe use SpanNearQuery will be helpful . But it seems that I can not add a WildcardQuery to the SpanNearQuery to match the birthday info.

I have totally got stucked . Any good suggestions ? Really Appreciate!

Comment: Lucene has Regex query support.

Answer (score 1):

There is not magic bullet to extract dates from a Lucene field that includes a bunch of text and a date format inside it.  The best way would be to write a custom analyzer that can break the terms apart during the indexing process and identify the numerical characters as a date.

I wrote a couple Analyzers for Lucene, however something like that is not really trivial...especially if you are new to Lucene.